# Change the zone interval in rasterVis horizonplot

Tags: r, raster, lattice, r-raster, rastervis

I'm working with `rasterVis` `horizonplot` function and I want to change the zone interval; for example I want to show the average for every 10 latitudinal zones in the `x axis`. This is [an example](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#spacetime) from `rasterVis` library.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
horizonplot(SSTanom, col.regions = rev(brewer.pal(n = 10, 'RdBu')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zones are determined by the `zonal` function, that is indirectly accesible via the `digits` argument (integer, number of digits to maintain). With this approach you don't have full control of the number of intervals. For example:

```
horizonplot(SSTanom, digits = -1)
```

[image: horizonplot and digits]

Another solution is the `dirXY` argument of `horizonplot` which gives more flexibility. For example:

```
horizonplot(SSTanom, dirXY = cut(y, 10))
```

[image: horizonplot and cut]

Unfortunately, `cut` does not preserve the label of the interval (because a `Raster` cannot store characters), so the name of each panel is not directly related to the zone.